# undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass in Rails Guide Section 5.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck at section 5.12 and I could not figure it out that how params[:post] is nil.
 The error message specifies the error occurs in the third line of this code:

```
      def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
          redirect_to @post
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end
```

My posts_controller file looks like this:

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @post = Post.new
      end

      def index
        @posts = Post.all
      end

      def create
        @post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text))
        if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      end

      def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
          redirect_to @post
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Sure.Already accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `edit` action is used to render the `edit` post page. So, you won't get params[:post]. It will always be nil. Hence, the error.

So your `edit` action should be:

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

After this you need to add the following `update` action in your controller which would be called upon submitting the form on `edit` post page.

```
 def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

This will take care of current issue.

**NOTE:**

I would highly recommend to move the repetitive logic for `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)` into a private method as suggested by @user3317140 in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: 
`add a check for :post`

```
if params.has_key?(:post)
  @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
  redirect_to @post
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

Add this at the end of your class PostsController < ApplicationController

```
private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

Comment: thank u very much,now I figure out how this problem came out.

Comment: Also recommend reading Michael Hartl's http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: Ok.thank u.I will read this book.I think it would help me a lot learning RoR :)